# Dynamic Links are not redirecting the user on appstore for downloading application on iOS Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I have been working on an application and I have integrated `Firebase Dynamic Links` to share user portfolio, etc which works well on Android and also on iOS the application is installed, but I want to redirect the user to appstore for downloading the application which dynamic links are doing fine on android but on iOS it is throwing this error.

[image]

I have added all the required configurations.

This is how, I am passing parameters to generate a link within application:

```
IOSParameters ios = IOSParameters(
  bundleId: AppStrings.package,
  fallbackUrl: Uri.parse('https://apps.apple.com/us/app/voino-app/id6467832056'),
  appStoreId: '6467832056',
  minimumVersion: '1',
);
```

Also, I have added the domain name in associated domain capability over xcode and well and info.plist also contains this:

```
<dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>Bundle Id</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.voinoapps.voino</string>
                <string>https</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
```

By running https://domain.page.link/apple-app-site-association, is giving this output:

```
{"applinks":{"apps":[],"details":[{"appID":"4ZDKH8VB6A.com.appname.admin","paths":["NOT /_/*","/*"]},{"appID":"4ZDKH8VB6A.com.appname.bundleid","paths":["NOT /_/*","/*"]}]}}
```